# Proving $d(dx)=d^2x$

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, education, differentials

Is it possible to carry out the following differential in Mathematica?

$$d(dx) = d^2x$$

I tried to write:

```
Dt[1*Dt[x]]
```

the result is:

```
Dt[Dt[x]]
```

instead of Dt^2[x].

Thank you so much for your willingness.

Comment: For exterior derivatives $d(df)=0$ is the defining property.

Comment: @Yarchik I suspect the context here is that of partial differential operators e.g. d/dx (with rounded d's).